# How to make flask jinja use variables from python list as a jinja expression variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

So I have a list:

```
ABC = ['{{ row[0] }}','{{ row[1] }}','{{ row[2] }}']
```

In HTML template, I want to use each items in list ABC as Jinja expression, how can i do it, here is my HTML table template

```
{% for row in reports %}
    <tr>
    {% for item in ABC %}
        <td>{{ item }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I tried to remove {{ }} from each item in ABC list, but it didn't work. It seemed like each item in HTML template was treated as a string, can't use by each row in reports.

In HTML page, the table render like this:

Column1      | Column2      | Column3

{{ row[0] }} | {{ row[1] }} | {{ row[2] }}

I want it work like this.

```
{% for row in reports %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ row[0] }}</td>
        <td>{{ row[1] }}</td>
        <td>{{ row[2] }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Edit: I have change to another solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you are creating the list. Right now you're giving it strings that identify the items you want to output. Instead, give it what you want to output.

```
ABC = [row[0], row[1], row[2]]
```

Edit: Since you are trying to print all of the columns in the template you can just iterate over them there.

```
{% for column in row %}
    <td>{{ column }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I can't define a list like this in python `ABC = [row[0], row[1], row[2]]` because row defined in HTML template `{% for row in reports %}`

Comment: Then why do you need `ABC` at all?

Comment: I want to make a table HTML template with given column name and each <td> variables. Because I have a few table HTML template with different column name and each <td> variables.

Comment: I think my solution is not good, so I rethink to create a separate HTML template file and include with `{% include('table_template_1.html') %}`.

Comment: Moving what you're doing to another template isn't necessary. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I mean, i want row[0] can be used by row in `{% for row in reports %}`. Just reports has data, row[0], row[1], row[2] don't has any data, just a temporary name, and the order can change.

Comment: At this point it's unclear what exactly you're trying to do. Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39738423/edit) to include more details. What might help is if you gave an example of `reports` as well as your desired output. Then we could help you bridge the gap between them.

Comment: I have changed to another solution, thank you anyway. :D